# What is an image vector?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, vector

Can some one please explain me what an image vector is? In the OpenCV library, the `imread` function is used to convert an image to a vector. Where can I see the source code for `imread`?

Can someone provide me with the code or an algorithm to convert an image to a vector?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/05b15943d6a42c99e5f921b7dbaa8323f3c042c6/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp#L427

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please provide more details on why you want to do this? Any code that you have already written? This might help others to identify the problem and help you. Thanks!

Comment: actually I am beginner on this topic and I want to do InDepth Research on this one,that's why I want to see code of imread function.

Answer (score 2):

Opencv reads and elaborates images as numeric structures, in this case matrices (or 2 dimensional vector if you like).

So an image of 3x3 pixel (in grayscale) may be read by opencv as

```
240 234 232
235 35  145
230 230 148
```

i.e in python the command

```
img = cv2.imread('abc.jpg')
```

read the image abc.jpg file, converts it as a numeric structure and stores the values in the variable img. You could verify it by printing the variable in the command line (but usually images loaded as matrices or vector are too big to be printed in numbers without confusion)